# Caps Lock as Tmux prefix key

Tags: vim, tmux

I am playing with Tmux and VIM and  I would use Caps Lock key as a prefix.

Which TOKEN I have to specify in the "set" configuration directive to enable Caps Lock as prefix?

For example, `set -g prefix TOKEN`

Answer (score 0):

I do not use tmux, but for my windowmanager i mapped the caps lock key to another windowskey using xmodmap. Here is th e specific code from my `.Xmodmaprc`

```
keycode  66    = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
add control    = Control_L
clear lock
```

Hope this helps.